# Parcelable vs Serializable - for classes without any fields

Tags: java, android, serialization, parcelable

Often I have to pass to *fragment* (or to *activity*) some *interface* instance without any internal data. To pass it to *fragment* (or *activity*), I should write it to `Bundle` (or `Intent`) as `Parcelable` or `Serializable`. What do I choose from these two options ?

Example:

```
public class SomeFragment {

    public static interface Helper {
        View prepareView(SomeFragment fragment, LayoutInflater inflater);
        // etc.
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return extractHelperFromArguments().prepareView(this, inflater);
    }

    public static SomeFragment newInstance(Helper helper) {
        SomeFragment fragment = new SomeFragment();
        // 
        // Bundle args = new Bundle();
        //
        // args.putParcelable(KEY_HELPER, (Parcelable) helper);
        // or
        // args.putSerializable(KEY_HELPER, (Serializable) helper);
        // ?
        //
        // fragment.setArguments(args)
        return fragment;
    }

}
```

If I choose `Parcelable` then I have to declare static field `CREATOR` and empty methods `describeContents()` and `writeToParcel()` (*empty* because the class doesn't have fields).

If I choose `Serializable` then I don't have to do anything.

*Sorry for my English*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi here is good link after reading this you will have no more questions regarding Parcelable vs Serializable..

[link](http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/parcelable-vs-java-serialization-in-android-app-development)

[image]

Comment: if the speed factor was just 2 like on image above i wouldnt bother in implementing Parcelable, in fact i beleive this one is closer to truth: http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/

Comment: @pskink LOL. Thanks for sharing the link. Parcelable is the way to go despite the simplicity of implementing serializable.

Comment: This answer's misleading, as the question is specifically about objects that have no fields. The cost of traditional serialization comes from reflection over the class variables, which doesn't cost anything if there aren't any variables to reflect over.